# How to get the web data using requests and pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-requests, pyqt5

I want to get the data from `http://www.sse.com.cn/assortment/stock/list/info/announcement/index.shtml`

You can see five boxes.
I would like to input the information as shown in the figure.
[image]

I tried to use `requests`

```
import requests

url = r'http://www.sse.com.cn/assortment/stock/list/info/announcement/index.shtml'
payload = {'inputCode': '600000', 'single_select_2':'DQGG', 'start_date': '2018-06-01', 'end_date':'2019-01-23'}
response = requests.post(url, data = payload)
```

However, I cannot get the correct result.

What should be the correct approach?

How to do it using `pyqt5`?

Comment: What data do you want to obtain? Do you want to download the pdf?

Comment: No, I just want to obtain the web page after pressing `submit`.

Comment: I mean do you want to fill out the form, press the button and get the HTML of the updated page?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I would say to use selenium for this operation as you need to add values to boxes and return HTML, it would be easier. Because this is not an api this is a page where you enter values, if it would be api then yes, after sending request you would get response and it would be what you want but now in my opinion seleniums is best approach.

Comment: Selenium is slow. How to use `requests`?

Comment: @Chan isn't `pyqt5` is used to create GUI applications.. what does it have to do with data retrieving??

Comment: @Chan Do you just want the HTML that is returned after you send in your request? I don't know Chinese, but if you `print(response.text)` do you get the web page you want?

Comment: @Anwarvic `pyqt5` can be used to get the html page and it can control javascript. But I don't familiar with it.

Comment: @Jack `response.text` is not the webpage I want. The javascript generating page needs to be taken care of.

Comment: I can get the next page using selenium but I am confused about what data you actually want from that page.

Comment: @Chan Is it possible to use a JavaScript (Node.js) based solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Python Selenium to achieve this. Post APIs are not public neither you know the data they require, so it cannot be used other than developers.

Try using Selenium, its very easy for Web scraping and Web Automation. Here are some head start commands/functions.

```
driver.get(web_url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).send_keys('asd')
```